Node express api stopped working after adding ssl certificate with domain to frontend app
I've been working on a project locally for a while now, its comprised of a react frontend app and an express backend app, the frontend is running on port 6969 and the backend runs on 6868, previously I request the backend with http://localhost:6868/endpoint it works fine, recently I purchased a domain and a ssl certificate and deployed my app on a digital ocean droplet.
after deploying using nginx and adding the domain + certificate to the frontend app, none of the api calls are going through, I tried:



Request URL
Result




https://localhost:6868
(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED


http://localhost:6868
(failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED


https://64.227.113.122:6868
(failed)net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR


http://64.227.113.122:6868
(blocked:mixed-content)


http://mazad.social:6868
(blocked:mixed-content)


https://www.mazad.social:6868
(failed)net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR



Bonus!! weird behaviors:
for http://www.moazad.social:6868 ->
opening https://64.227.113.122:6969(FRONTEND PORT) works (API requests go through), but opening https://www.mazad.social/home -> (blocked:mixed-content)
here's my nginx config:
# default config
.
.
.

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mazad.social;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mazad_social/ssl_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mazad_social/www.mazad.social.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

I expect that I still access my website through https://www.mazad.social/home while the API works fine, I really don't know where the fix is, is it from Nginx or code or Docker config.
all help is appreciated, don't hesitate to ask for extra information!!

You can't access https://www.mazad.social when your proxy's config is clearly configured for https://mazad.social
You're trying to access https://64.227.113.122:6969 but 6969 open as you are only listening on 443 (listen 443 ssl)!

Well with the current situation, It works, also I can only access mazad through www.mazad.social, I am still new to this I don't understand as much as I follow tutorials

You seem like you know about this stuff, what do you recommend I change?
